# How to make a pointer matrix getter in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, getter

As I say in the title, how can i writte the function getBoard() which has to return the private variable m_board.

M_board is a non-dynamic matrix of pointers to other class called Box

```
class Board
{
public:

    Board() {}

    void initializeBoard();
    void putPieces(vector<vector<Pice*>>& player1, vector<vector<Pice*>>& player2);

    Box* getBoard() { return m_board; }
    
    static void convertCoordinates(char rowAct, int colAct, int& row, int& col);
private:

    Box* m_board[COL][ROW];
};
```

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector` and avoid `new[]` for `m_board`.

Comment: Do you mean `Piece` instead of `Pice`?

Comment: Do you really need to return a pointer to the entire `m_board` array?  Or return just a specific `Box*` in the array?

Comment: Also `initializeBoard()` seems like a constructor, should be `Board()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I need to get the entire matrix to use it in other class. This matrix contains pointers to diferents "Box"

Comment: @tadman True i will delete initializeBoard() and use Board().
Yes I mean Piece sry, my bad.
But using vector I get a dynamic array, is it?

Comment: Unrelated: If you have a `public` getter that provides direct, modifiable  access to a `private` member, that member is now effectively `public` and you've broken encapsulation. It's far better to have a method that allows the caller to manipulate the object, than it is to return the object's `private` data and allow the caller to directly manipulate the data. With a method, he object can defend itself against stupidity on the part of the caller by testing and rejecting bad inputs.

Comment: Also note that it is annoying to return an array in C++. This is likely the problem you've run into. If you have to return anything, follow Remy's advice above and only provide access to small portions  to minimize the damage the user can cause all at once. The caller should be able to iterate through the grid through a function interface just as easily as they can iterate through the returned array. Eg `dostuff(b.getcell(x, y));` isn't that different from `dostuff(cellarray[[x][y]);`. A decent compiler will optimize out a simple function call for identical performance.

Comment: If you have to return the entire array, it can be as simple as `auto getBoard() { return m_board; }`  But I would opt for `Box* getBox(int col, int row) { return m_board[col][row]; }` instead.

Comment: One thing complicating this design is the pervasive use of pointers with no clear ownership. This is where having a boring, but simple `std::vector<Box>` as your board makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to build a two dimensional cellular automaton. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton

As several comments have suggested, this is more easily done using modern C++ code, which means std::vector and smart pointers.

I have found that doing this comes up again and again.  So it has a good idea to create some basic code to organize a two dimensional grid of cells.  Later on, whenever you need to do something like this, you can copy the basic code and focus on coding the detailed behaviour of the cells ( boxes in your particular case ) without having to invent the 2D grid behaviour over and over again.

Here is a suggested class interface for 2D cell automatons.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
namespace cell
{

/// Individual cell
class cCell
{
public:
    cCell();
    int ID()
    {
        return myID;
    }
    static void RestartID()
    {
        myLastID = -1;
    }
private:
    static int myLastID;
    int myID;
};
typedef std::shared_ptr< cCell > cell_t;

/// A 2D cell automaton
class cAutomaton
{
public:
    /** CTOR
        @param[in] w width
        @param[in] h height
    */
    cAutomaton(
        int w, int h );

    /** Pointer to cell
        @param[in] w zero-based width index
        @param[in] h zero-based height index
        @return shared pointer to cell

        The pointer can be used to acess methods of specialized cell class.

        Exception thrown if w or h out of bounds
    */
    cell_t cell(
        int w, int h );

    /** neighbours
        @param[in] w zero-based width index of cell
        @param[in] h zero-based height index of cell
        @return vector of shared pointers to cell's neighbours
    */
    std::vector< cell_t > neighbours(
        int w, int h );

    /** w, h co-ordinates of cell
        @param[out] w width
        @param[out] h height
        @param[in] cell
    */
    void coords(
                int& w, int& h,
                cell_t cell );

private:
    std::vector< cell_t > myCell;
    int myWidth;
    int myHeight;
};
}
```

You can take a look at one way to implement this at https://github.com/JamesBremner/autocell